# How are the Blathereen killed at the end?

Tags: doctor-who, the-sarah-jane-adventures

In *The Sarah Jane Adventures* episode "The Gift", how are the Blathereen aliens killed at the end?

Answer (score 2):

Per [wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Gift_(The_Sarah_Jane_Adventures));

> Enraged at their plans being ruined, the Blathereen teleport to the attic and threaten to destroy everyone. **Mr Smith generates the same frequency, destroying the partially digested Rakweed in their stomachs. The resultant build-up of methane gas in the Blathereens' stomachs causes them to explode.** Clyde is then told to clean up the mess and they all later celebrate with a barbecue.

and from the [episode transcript](http://www.chakoteya.net/SJA/312.htm);

> **RANI:** *What did you do?*
>
> **SARAH JANE:** *On their ship, all they did was stuff their faces with Rakweed. I knew their stomachs would still be full of it.*
>
> **K9:** *The destruction of the undigested Rakweed created methane gas. It could not be contained.*
>
> **CLYDE:** *So they farted themselves to death?*
>
> **K9:** *In a nutshell, Master Clyde.*